Почему nuxt 3 не видит state Pinia?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, установил Pinia всё как написано в документации, но state никак не отображается в devTools Nuxt. В чём может быть проблема?
nuxt.config:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  css: ['~/assets/styles/main.scss'],
  modules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
})

pinia:
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useStore = defineStore('store', () => {
  const isAuthenticated = ref<boolean>(false);

  return {
    isAuthenticated,
  };
})

package.json:
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "nuxt": "^3.12.3",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "latest",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.77.8"
  }
}


Подскажите, а где вы его вызываете и по каким причинам он должен отображаться?

@Molof, спасибо за подсказку, вызвал стор и состояние появилось
